# Firebird foreign key and references from another table

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

So I have a problem with adding foreign key to my table "Tekmovalec". I would like to add new key to that table by using references from another table called "Kraj". Somehow I always get error when I try to add foreign key, so I made new database again and copied all commands I have done so far, here.
So Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work?

making new database:

```
SQL> create database "c:\Baze\Tekmovanje.fdb" user 'sysdba' password 'masterkey';

SQL> create domain Rezultat as integer default 18 not null
CON> check (value between 1 and 32);
SQL>

SQL> create table Tekmovalec(
CON> TekmovalecID integer not null,
CON> ime char(10) not null,
CON> priimek char(20) not null,
CON> vzdevek char(10),
CON> rojen date,
CON> tocke rezultat,
CON> primary key (tekmovalecID));
SQL>

SQL> create table Kraj(
CON> krajID int not null,
CON> imekraja char(20) not null,
CON> primary key(krajID));
SQL>

SQL> alter table Tekmovalec add foreign key (krajID) references kraj (krajID)
CON> on delete no action on update cascade;
SQL>
```

and then I get this error when I hit enter after alter table Tekmovalec add foreign key ....

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
unsuccessful metadata update
-Unknown columns in index RDB$FOREIGN3
SQL>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding `foreign key` relation, it is necessary to have joining column present in both the tables.

`krajID` column is present in `Kraj` table but it is missing in `Tekmovalec` table.

There are 2 thing that 2 can do:

1. Drop table `Tekmovalec` and recreate it by adding `krajID` column. Like:

   ```
   create table Tekmovalec(
       ....
       krajID int,
       primary key (tekmovalecID));
   ```
2. Alter the existing table and add new column. Like:

   ```
   alter table Tekmovalec add krajID int
   ```

[Add new column to table](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-alter-table.html#langrefupd20-at-contextvars)

Comment: so I have to drop table Tekmovalec and remake it? Is there no other way to add that column to existing table?

Comment: You can alter the table to add new column. Have a look @ following link: [Add new column to table] [http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-alter-table.html#langrefupd20-at-contextvars]

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining why adding the column solves the problem.